# Unable to unset Nuxt page transition

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

According to [the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/transitions#transition-mode):

> The default transition mode for pages differs from the default mode in Vue.js. The transition mode is by default set to out-in. If you want to run leaving and entering transitions simultaneously, you have to set the mode to the empty string mode: ''.

However I am finding that this doesn't take effect. I have two simple slide transitions that looks like this:

```css
    .fwd-leave-active,
    .back-leave-active,
    .fwd-enter-active,
    .back-enter-active {
      transition: all .5s ease;
    }
    
    .fwd-enter,
    .back-leave-to{
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .back-enter,
    .fwd-leave-to {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
```

I have tried setting the mode at the page level:

```js
    export default {
      name: 'Page2',
      transition: {
        name: 'fwd',
        mode: '',
      },
    }
```

And also at the config level:

```js
    pageTransition: {
      name: 'fwd',
      mode: '',
    },
```

Neither of these have the desired effect of running the transitions simultaneously. Changing to `in-out` does have an effect, but passing an empty string doesn't.

This is on Nuxt v2.15.8.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Not sure to fully understand. You want to achieve what exactly? Unsetting aka removing any kind of transition? Applying a transition on pages/layouts? There are quite some nice example here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/transitions#the-pagetransition-property Aren't any of those working properly? Since you're using the same styling for both `back` and `fwd` I may recommend using the default `page-*` by default. Is the issue located in the CSS itself maybe?

Comment: @kissu the tranistion is fine, but Nuxt adds a transition **mode** of `out-in` which means the transition **in** begins only after the transition **out** has happened. I need them to happen simultaneously.

Comment: I gave a [few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+transition) on the subject already, looking at them it looks like you could also try `in-out`. It's not a Nuxt issue per-se but more on how to achieve the desired effect with CSS, and if none of he modes work there it's maybe a CSS issue on how you are doing your things.

Comment: Thanks @kissu but `in-out` still doesn't run simultaneously. The exiting page won't transition out until the arriving page transitions in. The docs say this should be achievable but it just doesn't appear to work: `If you want to run leaving and entering transitions simultaneously, you have to set the mode to the empty string mode: ''.` https://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ shows an example of what I'm trying to achieve with the Left/Right transition. Both pages transition at the same time, so appear connected.

Comment: I guess it's a CSS issue to debug so. Hard to tell with just text. Somebody would need to try that one and inspect why it's not happening.